# How to check if a given file descriptor stored in a variable is still valid?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, file-descriptor

I have a file descriptor stored in a variable say var. How can I check whether that descriptor is valid at a later stage?

```
  fdvar1= open(.....);
  fdvar2 = fdvar1;       // Please ignore the bad design

  ....
  // lots of loops , conditionals and threads. It can call close(fdvar2) also.  
  ....

  if(CheckValid(fdvar1)) // How can I do this check  ?
    write(fdvar1, ....);
```

Now i want to check whether var1 (which still holds the opened descriptor) is still valid.
Any API's for that ?

Comment: Why is the FD copied at the C level instead of at the OS level?

Comment: See the manual page for [`dup`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup).

Comment: Even if you can check validity, the result is mostly worthless, because it's possible that another opened file received the same descriptor after the original was closed.

Comment: This is mentioned in TLPI exercise 5.4 quite clearly.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[`fcntl(fd, F_GETFD)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) is the canonical cheapest way to check that `fd` is a valid open file descriptor. If you need to batch-check a lot, using `poll` with a zero timeout and the `events` member set to 0 and checking for `POLLNVAL` in `revents` after it returns is more efficient.

With that said, the operation "check if a given resource handle is still valid" is almost always fundamentally incorrect. After a resource handle is freed (e.g. a fd is `close`d), its value may be reassigned to the next such resource you allocate. If there are any remaining references that might be used, they will wrongly operate on the new resource rather than the old one. Thus, the real answer is probably: If you don't already know by the logic of your program, you have major fundamental logic errors that need to be fixed.

Comment: @R Assuming I am trying to implement a library that handles a FD, for example the pipe library, and I am the one that passes the FD arguments to the programs that will be using my library is it still bad practice to test for FD validation? 
Or is it mandatory?

Comment: @petric: I don't understand your question. As a general answer, I'm going to say yes, it's bad (and meaningless) to "test for FD validation" but if you have specific concerns about what you're doing you should probably post a new question asking about it (and referring to this question/answer) rather than asking in a comment.

Comment: What if I have parent and child process sharing a pipe. In parent process I close the read end and write end of the pipe. Then the child process still has an valid read end. How does this work?

Comment: @HelpingBean: I don't see how that has anything to do with this question. If you have a real question there, please post it as a new question (and feel free to @ me here with a link to the new question).

Comment: That's interesting. But in case I'm unit testing a structure containg some file descriptors. And I want to test a function closing the file descriptors and reclaiming the memory. Would it be correct to check if the file descriptors are closed in such a case?

Comment: One reason one could want to do that: your program is called by a script which does "exec 0<&-; exec 1>&-; ./foobar". Here, you might want to check if the FDs are open or not. This kind of things can be setup in, for example, scripts starting daemons (as in daemontools, which have no reason to keep those FDs open).

Comment: "Thus, the real answer is probably: If you don't already know by the logic of your program, you have major fundamental logic errors that need to be fixed."

I don't think this is true - when a process starts, it could have inherited any number of open file descriptors (or none).

Comment: @craig65535: Unless your program was told via a command line interface documented to provide a contract for feeding in extra inherited file descriptors, *it does not own any of them*. For example they could be dummy pipes the invoking process is using to monitor when your process (and its children) have all exited. It's an error to try to poke at these.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the `fcntl()` function:

```
int fd_is_valid(int fd)
{
    return fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) != -1 || errno != EBADF;
}
```

Comment: `F_GETFD` is cheaper in principle since it only dereferences the (process-local) file descriptor in kernel space, not the underlying open file description (process-shared) which it refers to.

Comment: You should set `errno` to zero before calling `fcntl`. `errno` could equal `EBADF` before you call your function and `fcntl` will only change it in case of error.

Comment: @Bilow he's already checking for a return value of `-1`, which only happens "in case of error", so setting `errno` to 0 before the call would just be redundant.

Comment: @CraigBarnes Indeed

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is any function that can tell you if the descriptor is still valid.  The descriptor is typically just a small integer like 6 and your libc can choose to reuse that number if you close the file and open a new one later.

Instead, you should consider using `dup()` to copy the file descriptor.  By duplicating the file descriptor instead of using the same descriptor in multiple places, it might become easier for you to know whether the file descriptor is still valid.  You just have to remember to close both the original descriptor and the duplicated one when you are done.

Comment: David is "correct" in that you can't determine if a descriptor is "*still* valid". You can tell if it's valid, but this gives you no information about whether it still refers to the same resource or not.

Comment: Yes.  My definition of valid is that it still points to the same thing it used to.  I think that's a good definition because it's usually what you want and you can tell if the descriptor is still valid by just looking at the code; it doesn't depend on undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, using `dup` is decent advice *for OP's particular problem*. It would avoid the whole issue. A better approach might be to keep a flag in a separate variable indicating whether the file descriptor was already closed; this will avoid extra trips to kernelspace (and scarce resource consumption).

Comment: Hey guys, I updated my answer (over 2 years later) to be clearer.  I am not suggesting that you call `dup` just to see if the file descriptor is valid; I was trying to offer some design advice that might make it easier to avoid that situation in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

From [this](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/93683-checking-if-file-descriptor-valid.html#post678998) forum article:

```
int is_valid_fd(int fd)
{
    return fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) != -1 || errno != EBADF;
}
```

> fcntl(GETFL) is probably the cheapest and least likely to fail
>   operation you can perform on a file descriptor. In particular, the
>   specification suggests that it cannot be interrupted by signals, nor
>   is it affected by any sort of lock held anywhere.

Comment: How about attributing your sources: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/93683-checking-if-file-descriptor-valid.html#post678998

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that if you want to know if it still points to the same resource, one (non-perfect) approach would be to `fstat()` the descriptor just after open and then later you can do it again and compare the results.  Start by looking at `.st_mode`& `S_IFMT` and go from there -- is it a filesystem object? Look at `.st_dev / .st_ino.`  Is it a socket? Try `getsockname()`, `getpeername()`.  It won't be 100% certain, but it can tell you if it definitely isn't the same.

Answer (score -1):

i solved this problem for me. i don't know whether it can be used for general purpose but for serial connections it works fine (e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0)!

```
struct stat s;
fstat(m_fileDescriptor, &s);

// struct stat::nlink_t   st_nlink;   ... number of hard links 
if( s.st_nlink < 1 ){
 // treat device disconnected case
}
```

For details see e.g. man page http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat

Cheers,
Flo