# Detect if a file descriptor with O_NONBLOCK is still valid in a FFI scenario

Tags: c, linux, smalltalk, ffi

If I have a file descriptor that has been opened with `open (2)` and subsequently set to `O_NONBLOCK` using `fcntl (2)` using a FFI (Foreign Function Interface).

This means almost every call to `read (2)` will return -1, with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`, which means this time there was no data available.

Sadly, the FFI I am using cannot access the `errno` variable, so I cannot determine whether the -1 value was returned because there was no data or because the file handle is no longer valid.

So I am trying to determine somehow if the file descriptor is still valid without ever having to read `errno`. I [already tried all the answers with `fcntl` from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340695/how-to-check-if-a-given-file-descriptor-stored-in-a-variable-is-still-valid), but they don't work and never return -1.

Perhaps this is because I am reading a device file: `/dev/input/js0`?

Is there another function I can call that will tell me whether the file descriptor is invalid? (In the question above someone mentioned `poll`, but I am not sure how this was meant.)

I am using the Squeak FFI and am not allowed to add any custom C wrappers. I am trying to access a Gamepad and read button information from it, which is an optional assignment.

### Smalltalk Source Code of what I tried with fcntl:

The FFI for `fcntl` (defined in Class `Gamepad`):

```
manipulateFileHandle: fileHandle command: command
    < cdecl: long 'fcntl' ( long long ) module: 'libc.so.6' >
    ^ self externalCallFailed
```

Then in another method, I call it:

```
| handleTest |
handleTest := Gamepad manipulateFileHandle: externalFileHandle command: 1.
Transcript show: handleTest; cr.
```

The `command` 1 is `F_GETFD`, reading the file descriptor flags. But `handleTest` is never -1, even after unplugging the gamepad.

Comment: Make a C function that reads `errno` for you. Or throw away that FFI, it's garbage (I know you can't). Otherwise, make a custom `read()` wrapper that returns `errno` in a useful way.

Comment: Oh, how I would love to throw that FFI away. It's homework, and I am not allowed to add any extra wrappers... which is also ridiculous. The code will be automatically checked out and tested, if there was a dependency on a custom wrapper, it would fail.

Comment: You are not allowed to write any C code? Please specify such restrictions in the question. It sucks having to discover all the untold restrictions by repeatedly interrogating you. What system are you working on? Are you allowed to write unportable code? Because most libc implementations have a function that returns a pointer to `errno`.

Comment: Can you provide an illustrative program of what you tried so we can see if there is some bug you introduced that caused it to not work?

Comment: Your `fcntl` idea should have worked. After the FD is closed, it doesn't matter what kind of device it was originally open on.

Comment: @FUZxxl, yes I can write unportable code! It has to work on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit only. And sorry for not being specific enough, I added that part to the question.

Comment: @jxh, I added some source code, but since this is Squeak, it is impossible to paste a good overview because that would mean hundreds of clicks (god I hate that thing).

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. I thought so as well, but the call just never returns a negative value.

Comment: Can you dereference an `int *` in your smalltalk code? The function `__errno_location()` will return the address of the `errno` variable.

Comment: @jxh, I think so. It should be able to handle pointers using the `ExternalAddress` class. That might actually work, I will try that right away! Thank you

Comment: @NikontheThird Unplugging the device doesn't make the FD invalid. An FD doesn't become invalid until you call `close()` on it.

Comment: @Barmar, I did not know that. That explains everything. I just assumed that if the file does not exist anymore the descriptor would be invalid as well.

Comment: @NikontheThird That's Windows semantics. In POSIX semantics (what Linux does), a file is only ever actually removed when the last file descriptor to that file is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On GNU/Linux systems, `libc` contains the function `__errno_location()`, which returns the address of the `errno` variable. Your FFI should be able to invoke that function, and then dereference the address representing an `int *`.

Before GCC invented a syntax for thread local variables, the technique to allow multi-threaded code to safely manipulate `errno` was to define it as:

```
#define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

The function would return a thread local address. On your Linux system, if you use `gcc -E` on C code that uses `errno`, you will see the expansion.

> <sub>As explained by Barmar, the `fcntl()` techniques work. The reason it never returned `-1` was because you were still holding a valid file descriptor. A file descriptor does not become invalid until it is closed.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. The `__errno_location` call works, now I have access to `errno`. To anyone with the same issue: You have to define a separate class that derives from `ExternalStructure` in Squeak, otherwise you'll end up with an opaque `ExternalData` pointer. The fields: `fields ^#((errno   'long'))`, the FFI call: `< cdecl: StructureName* '__errno_location' () module: 'libc.so.6' >`