# How to check whether a thread of detached attribute releases the system resources after exit?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
void * fun1(void *arg) 
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("data","w+");
  if(fp==0)
  {
    perror("fopen");
    return NULL;
  }
  perror("fopen");
  fprintf(fp,"%s\n","file opened");
  return NULL;
}


void main() 
{  
 pthread_attr_t atr;
 pthread_attr_init(&atr);
 pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&atr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

 pthread_t thread1;
 pthread_create(&thread1,&atr,&fun1,NULL);
 pthread_attr_destroy(&atr);
 while(1);
}
```

i want to know if this thread will close the file pointer fp automatically or not after exiting.

Comment: You can't check in your code, after all, you detached the thread. Assuming your empty loop really keeps the process running, you *can* check from outside, using [`lsof`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) on linux.

Comment: I referred [this](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node30.html#SECTION003040000000000000000) and as per description, it seems that the file is closed in case of a detachable thread.
Also, you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340695/how-to-check-if-a-given-file-descriptor-stored-in-a-variable-is-still-valid) to check about open file descriptor.

Comment: @GauravPathak Note this says *thread resources* are being released when detached and ended, which is something different than *resources used by the thread*. No, no file descriptors are closed when a thread ends. The file descriptor table is a *shared resource* within a process and a specific fd is **not** owned by a specific thread.

Comment: @FelixPalmen `lsof` or similar will only give you the file descriptor.  If the code uses a `FILE *` to access the file - as in the example - there's no easy way to recover it, and it may irretrievably leaked.

Answer (score 2):

> i want to know if this thread will close the file pointer fp automatically or not after exiting.

No, it will not.

If the *process* exits, the file pointer and the underlying file descriptor/handle will be closed.

**Nothing will happen to the actual file pointer and underlying descriptor/handle when a thread exits.**  The file pointer will remain allocated with all its resources and the underlying descriptor/handle will remain open.  If your code does not otherwise track the file pointer, it will be leaked.

Comment: There's also a common, but very nasty pitfall when a thread inadvertantly closes an *fd* *twice* - This doesn't hurt in a single-threaded environment and will silently be ignored, but with multiple threads the fd could easily have been allocated for another thread between the first and second `close()`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't close it the file descriptor will remain allocated and that will cause a memory leak if your program exits without closing it. You've to explicitly close it with `close(fd)`.Detaching a thread will just let it terminates and releases its own resourses without the need to `pthread_join` it.

Comment: "*the file descriptor will remain allocated and that will cause a memory leak if your program exits without closing it*" well, any recent OS I know about closes file descriptors the moment a process (not thread) ends. So they do not leak then anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not.

Proof:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<unistd.h>

sem_t sem;

void * fun1(void *arg) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("data","w+");
    if(fp==0)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }
    perror("fopen");
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n","file opened");
    sleep(1);
    sem_post(&sem);
    return NULL;
}


int main() 
{  
    pthread_attr_t atr;
    pthread_attr_init(&atr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&atr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    sem_init(&sem, 0, 0);

    long pid = getpid();
    char cmd[] = 
        "echo ==================\n"
        "ls /proc/xxxxxx/fd\n"
        "ls /proc/xxxxxx/task\n"
        ;
    sprintf(cmd, 
        "echo ==================\n"
        "ls /proc/%ld/fd\n"
        "ls /proc/%ld/task\n"
        , pid, pid);

    system(cmd);


    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create(&thread1,&atr,&fun1,NULL);
    system(cmd);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&atr);

    sem_wait(&sem);
    sleep(1);


    system(
            cmd
          );
    return 0;
```

}

Possible output:

```
==================
0
1
2
30697
==================
0
1
2
3
30697
30702
==================
0
1
2
3
30697
```

As you can see, the newly opened fd (3) survives the death of the thread (30702). The detached attribute doesn't play a role here.